# Can't find web process procfile error with Windows Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I want to deploy my website which works locally, but runs an error when it tries to have a public instance.

I am on Windows 8.1 and following the official instructions have created a `Procfile.windows`. It looks like this:

```
web: python app.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

The build works, but then I get this error when I run `heroku ps:scale web=1`:

> Couldn't find that process type (web).

Repo [here](https://github.com/christina-zhou-96/SongsLikeThis/tree/public).

The official tutorial works, so there's definitely proof of concept of this working somehow.

Answer (score 0):

> I am on Windows 8.1 and following the official instructions have created a `Procfile.windows`

Why did you name this file `Procfile.windows`? [The documentation is quite clear](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location):

> The Procfile is always a simple text file that is named Procfile *without a file extension*. For example, `Procfile.txt` is not valid.

Rename it to `Procfile` and redeploy.

Once you've got that working, install a WSGI server and use that instead of `manage.py runserver`, which [isn't suitable for production use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Gunicorn is probably the most common choice, but I don't think it works on Windows so you won't be able to use it in your development environment. uWSGI or Waitress should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, while the web instance starts, it now crashes after removing .windows from Procfile. (Also, the tut code has a .windows file.)

Comment: @ChristinaZhou, I don't know what tutorial you are using, but it definitely should _not_ have a file extension. What message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up switching to Waitress successfully - I didn't type in the right command at the start but then found it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Waitress and changed my Procfile to
`web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT app:app`

I also removed the .windows extension, which is meant for local development.

It works fine now!

(My equivalent to "main.py" was "app.py" so you'd likely change this for your needs to `{main.py}:app`)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your procfile to look like

```
    web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app
```

And your procfile.windows filed as

```
    web: python app.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```